# ActiveRecord dynamic finders for uppercase field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Working with a legacy table that uses upper-case for column names.  Renaming the columns is not an option.

I'm attempting to locate a record using the table/model's `COLUMN_NAME` attribute.

These statements:

```
c = MetaColumn.find_by_COLUMN_NAME('PATIENT_ID')
c = MetaColumn.find_by_column_name('PATIENT_ID')
```

generate an error:

```
formal argument cannot be a constant
          def self.find_by_name(COLUMN_NAME, options = {})
```

These statements work as expected:

```
> c = MetaColumn.find_by column_name: 'PATIENT_ID'
> c = MetaColumn.find_by COLUMN_NAME: 'PATIENT_ID'
```

Is there a way to indicate that `COLUMN_NAME` is a field, not a constant?

Comment: `MetaColumn.find_by 'COLUMN_NAME' => 'PATIENT_ID'`

Answer (score 0):

You could alias the columns names:

`alias_attribute :new_column_name, :real_column_name`

Of course, if nothing else touches that DB, you could consider renaming the column names:

```
 class ChangeOldColumnToNewColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
          rename_column :tableName, :oldColumn, :newColumn
      end
 end
```

Comment: Tried the alias approach earlier: it generates the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to modify your method missing to upcase your search query to reflect the DB, so that your methods looks "rails-like" for anyone coming after you. Try the following, which should allow you to still use methods like `find_by_column` and just translate it to uppercase behind the scenes.

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &blk)
  m = m.to_s.upcase if @attributes.include? m.to_s.upcase.gsub(/=/, '')
  super(m, *args, &blk)
end
```